# Text.Contains if Text contains keyword as subtext

Tags: excel, split, powerquery, contains

I wish to split the sexes of animals from sentences shown in the desired column using Text.Contains:

[image]

In this slightly unusual case male is contained within female and so all results return male.

How can I Modify this code to achieve this?

Current M Code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "male", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Male" else null)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

update:

This is my current solution:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Females", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "Female", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Female" else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Males", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "Male", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Male" else null),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Sex", each if [Females] = "Female" then "Female" else if [Males] = "Male" then "Male" else null),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Column1", "Sex"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

However, I don't really like the need for multiple Custom columns and feel there will be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why don't you check for "female" and then return "Female" for true and "male" for false? `if Text.Contains([Column1], "female", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "Female" else "Male"`

Comment: Ah I've just updated a scenario where neither sex is given in the sentence (in which case return blank). Though I think your suggestion leads me to a way to achieve this. Just wondering if there is a neater way.

Comment: You could add a second `Text.Contains([Column1], "male" .... then "Male" else NULL` replacing the first `else`-statment for "Male" - this second check won't find "female" as it is already handled by the first text.contains-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to split the input into a list-object and check if the list contains either "female" or "male" (or neither):

```
if List.Contains(Text.Split([column1]," "), "female") then "female" else if List.Contains(Text.Split([current]," "), "male") then "male" else null
```

Or, in `M-Code`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if List.Contains(Text.Split([column1]," "), "female") then "female" else if List.Contains(Text.Split([column1]," "), "male") then "male" else null)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

---

Maybe, if you want to run the risk of retrieving false positives, try `List.FindText`:

```
List.First(List.FindText(Text.Split([column1]," "),"male"))
```

Or in `M-Code`:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"current", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.First(List.FindText(Text.Split([column1]," "),"male")))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: @Nick, I added an even much simpler method however it may be prone to false positives depending on your data.

Comment: Cool Solution +1 as always, because if there was an option to upvote a million, i would have done that as well!